# SQL Oracle Sub-query

Tags: subquery, teradata

I am having a issue getting this Sub-query to run. I am using Toad Data Point -Oracle. I get syntax error. I have tried several different ways with no luck. I am knew to sub-query's

```
Select *
from FINC.VNDR_ITEM_M as M
where M.ACCT_DOC_NBR = A.ACCT_DOC_NBR
(SELECT A.CLIENT_ID,
       A.SRC_SYS_ID,
       A.CO_CD,
       A.ACCT_NBR,
       A.CLR_DT,
       A.ASGN_NBR,
       A.FISCAL_YR,
       A.ACCT_DOC_NBR,
       A.LINE_ITEM_NBR,
       A.MFR_PART_NBR,
       A.POST_DT,
       A.DRCR_IND, 
       A.DOC_CRNCY_AMT, 
       A.CRNCY_CD, 
       A.BSL_DT        
FROM FINC.VNDR_ITEM_F A
WHERE A.CLR_DT IN (SELECT MAX(B.CLR_DT)
                  FROM FINC.VNDR_ITEM_F AS B
                  where (B.ACCT_DOC_NBR = A.ACCT_DOC_NBR and B.FISCAL_YR=A.FISCAL_YR and B.LINE_ITEM_NBR = A.LINE_ITEM_NBR and B.SRC_SYS_ID =A.SRC_SYS_ID and B.POST_DT=A.POST_DT and B.CO_CD=A.CO_CD) 
                  and (B.CO_CD >='1000' and  B.CO_CD <= '3000'  or B.CO_CD ='7090') and (B.POST_DT Between to_date ('08/01/2018','mm/dd/yyyy')
                                        AND to_date ('08/31/2018', 'mm/dd/yyyy')) and (B.SRC_SYS_ID ='15399') and (B.FISCAL_YR ='2018'))
GROUP BY 
       A.CLIENT_ID,
       A.SRC_SYS_ID,
       A.CO_CD,
       A.ACCT_NBR,
       A.CLR_DT,
       A.ASGN_NBR,
       A.FISCAL_YR,
       A.ACCT_DOC_NBR,
       A.LINE_ITEM_NBR,
       A.MFR_PART_NBR,
       A.POST_DT,
       A.DRCR_IND, 
       A.DOC_CRNCY_AMT, 
       A.CRNCY_CD,
       A.BSL_DT)
```

Comment: What syntax error do you get? Please remember we do not have access to your schema so we cannot compile your code. You will get a quicker answer if you narrow down our search.

Comment: Teradata exception: [Teradata Database] [3706] Syntax error: expected something between ')' and the 'join' keyword.

Comment: I am trying different things like; Select *
from FINC.VNDR_ITEM_M as M
where (M.ACCT_DOC_NBR = A.ACCT_DOC_NBR) join

Comment: Also please explain what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to reference the sub-query in the FROM clause? If so, what are the join conditions?

Comment: The word "join" does not appear in the posted query. So clearly Teradata is complaining about a different version of the code from the one shown here. Please make sure your post is consistent.

Comment: I want the results from the bottom subquery and get results from table VNDR_ITEM_M by joining results the sub-query. joins would be M.ACCT_DOC_NBR = A.ACCT_DOC_NBR and M.CO_CD=A.CO_CD

Comment: The syntax error without the word "Join" is; Syntax error, expected something like ';' between ')' and '('.

Comment: "Teradata Database"? Why is this tagged for Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is broken, you put subquery just at the end. Now it looks like:

```
select *
from dual as m 
where a.dummy = m.dummy
(select dummy from dual)
```

It is in incorrect place, not joined, not aliased. What you should probably do is:

```
select *
from dual m 
join (select dummy from dual) a on a.dummy = m.dummy
```

You also have some redundant, unnecessary brackets, but that's minor flaw. Full code (I cannot test it without data access):

```
select *
from FINC.VNDR_ITEM_M M
join (SELECT A.CLIENT_ID, A.SRC_SYS_ID, A.CO_CD, A.ACCT_NBR, A.CLR_DT, A.ASGN_NBR,
               A.FISCAL_YR, A.ACCT_DOC_NBR, A.LINE_ITEM_NBR, A.MFR_PART_NBR, A.POST_DT,
               A.DRCR_IND, A.DOC_CRNCY_AMT, A.CRNCY_CD, A.BSL_DT
          FROM FINC.VNDR_ITEM_F A
          WHERE A.CLR_DT IN (SELECT MAX(B.CLR_DT)
                               FROM FINC.VNDR_ITEM_F AS B
                               where B.ACCT_DOC_NBR = A.ACCT_DOC_NBR 
                                 and B.FISCAL_YR=A.FISCAL_YR 
                                 and B.LINE_ITEM_NBR = A.LINE_ITEM_NBR 
                                 and B.SRC_SYS_ID =A.SRC_SYS_ID 
                                 and B.POST_DT=A.POST_DT 
                                 and B.CO_CD=A.CO_CD 
                                 and (('1000'<=B.CO_CD and B.CO_CD<='3000') or B.CO_CD='7090') 
                                 and B.POST_DT Between to_date ('08/01/2018', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
                                                   AND to_date ('08/31/2018', 'mm/dd/yyyy') 
                                 and B.SRC_SYS_ID ='15399' and B.FISCAL_YR ='2018')
          GROUP BY A.CLIENT_ID, A.SRC_SYS_ID, A.CO_CD, A.ACCT_NBR, A.CLR_DT, A.ASGN_NBR, 
                   A.FISCAL_YR, A.ACCT_DOC_NBR, A.LINE_ITEM_NBR, A.MFR_PART_NBR, A.POST_DT, 
                   A.DRCR_IND, A.DOC_CRNCY_AMT, A.CRNCY_CD, A.BSL_DT) A
    on M.ACCT_DOC_NBR = A.ACCT_DOC_NBR and M.CO_CD=A.CO_CD;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an alias to the SubSelect (or *Derived Table* in Standard SQL):

```
select *
from
 ( select .......
 ) AS dt
join ....
```

Comment: This is what I put, but isn't working..                                                                     
Select *
from FINC.VNDR_ITEM_M as M
(select A.ACCT_DOC_NBR, A.CO_CD, A.FISCAL_YR as dt
join A.ACCT_DOC_NBR on M.ACCT_DOC_NBR